# Why aren't UNIX domain sockets removed automatically when no longer referenced?

Tags: linux, posix, unix-socket

When a process binds a name to a TCP socket (i.e. ip:port pair) and exits, it doesn't has to explicitly cleanup anything: another process can reuse the same ip:port. Same with the abstract UNIX sockets on Linux (when `sun_path` starts with zero byte). However, when using traditional UNIX sockets, one has to `unlink` it after it is no longer needed (or before `bind`-ing, which is not very good since you can remove something important).

According to my observations, once the last file descriptor referring to the UNIX socket is closed, the socket file is useless garbage: `open` returns `ENODEV`, `connect` returns `ECONNREFUSED`, and `bind` returns `EADDRINUSE`. The only thing one can (and has to) do is `unlink`.

Shouldn't OS remove socket file from file system automatically when it's no longer used?

Comment: I might argue that the correct thing for the system to do would be to allow rebinding to a lingering socket file, just like rebinding to a TCP port is allowed. This would actually be nice, since it would be possible to manually set socket permissions and have them remain. Nevertheless, it would be interesting if anyone knows the reason for the current behavior.

Comment: Questions about the design of Unix would be more appropriate for unix.SE than SO.

Comment: Socket files never get opened by any process and therefore there is no inodes or descriptors to check if it is in use. _**Names in the UNIX domain are only used for establishing connections. They are not used for message delivery once a connection is established. Therefore, in contrast with the Internet domain, unbound sockets need not be (and are not) automatically given addresses when they are connected.**_ - excerpt from http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/netguide/dusockD.binding_names.html

Comment: You would be better off asking this question on unix.stackexchange.com or serverfault.com

Comment: @Dolda2000 Makes sense. Surprisingly, setting `SO_REUSEADDR` before binding doesn't allow to rebind to the existing socket.

Comment: @alvits I think this excerpt means that once UNIX domain connection is established, the socket which **`connect`**-ed doesn't has a name, i.e., `getsockname` returns nothing, as opposed to `AF_INET` sockets where connected sockets are assigned some IP address and random port.